# INSERT from SAS 9.2 to SQL Server 2005 fails when table has a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sas

I connect to an SQL Server 2005 DB from SAS 9.2 via SAS/Access ODBC Driver. 
In the DB, I have a table `my_table`, which has an INSERT-trigger that copies all the inserted rows into another table in the database. In the SQL Server environment, the trigger works normally. However, **SAS Proc SQL** doesn't seem to get on well with a table with trigger. The following statement

```
proc sql ;
    INSERT INTO my_db.my_table
    SELECT a, b, c
    FROM my_db.my_test_table ;
quit ;
```

runs without complaint w/o the trigger, but when I enable the trigger, it hangs!

Could anyone shed a light to this?

Comment: Did you try to send your query using "SQL passthrough" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make sure that the triggers start with this line of code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

This prevents the sql server from returning the number of records affected by an operation.